# 2 setInterval() instance are running, how to run one?

Tags: javascript, function, variables, setinterval

## doubles setInterval() instance are running, how to run one ?

```js
var odo = document.querySelector(".odometer");
var ve = document.getElementById("viewers");
var input = document.querySelector("#inputUserName");

function handleEnter(e) {
  var keycode = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
  if (keycode == "13") {
    console.log("You pressed enter!");
    var identifiant = input.value;
    main(identifiant);
  }
}

function main(identifiant) {
  streamViewers(identifiant);

  function streamViewers(v) {
    var refreshV = setInterval(() => { // var refreshV is for stop the interval on bad response
      fetch(`https://api.twitch.tv/helix/streams?user_id=${v}`, {
        headers: {
          "client-id": "0ikjx4yg4ifvnm010hu1p5w8c4pjgm"
        }
      })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            // here is my fetch function 
          console.log("Running setInterval() with v = " + v)
        });

    }, 2000);
    console.log("xx");
  }
}
```

### Step 1

- Enter a value in the input: "string 1"
- Tap enter key

*OUTPUT*

```
You pressed enter!
xx
Running setInterval() with v = string 1
Running setInterval() with v = string 1
...
```

### Step 2

- Enter a new value in the input: "string 2"
- Tap enter key

*OUTPUT*

```
...
You pressed enter!
xx
Running setInterval() with v = string 1
Running setInterval() with v = string 2
Running setInterval() with v = string 1
Running setInterval() with v = string 2
...
```

2 instance of my main() function are running, i want 1 instance.

### How to run once a function ?

Comment: Your `main` function is starting a `setInterval` when you enter a string. When you re-enter a string you start another instance of a `setInterval` without stopping the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign the interval to a global variable. Then you should clear the old interval before starting a new one.

```js
var odo = document.querySelector(".odometer");
var ve = document.getElementById("viewers");
var input = document.querySelector("#inputUserName");
var refreshV;

function handleEnter(e) {
  var keycode = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
  if (keycode == "13") {
    console.log("You pressed enter!");
    var identifiant = input.value;
    main(identifiant);
  }
}

function main(identifiant) {
  streamViewers(identifiant);

  function streamViewers(v) {
    clearInterval(refreshV);
    refreshV = setInterval(() => { response
      fetch(`https://api.twitch.tv/helix/streams?user_id=${v}`, {
          headers: {
            "client-id": "0ikjx4yg4ifvnm010hu1p5w8c4pjgm"
          }
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
          // here is my fetch function 
          console.log("Running setInterval() with v = " + v)
        });

    }, 2000);
    console.log("xx");
  }
}
```